# Remap Esc key in Vim

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Is it possible to remap the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to another key in Vim?  When I'm using Vim in a full screen VMware vSphere web client console window and I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to exit edit mode, it also takes me out of full screen mode in the console window.

I am using the Vim that comes from the RHEL YUM repo. (RHEL 7.5; Vim 7.4).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459901/remap-esc-key-in-vim

Comment: Whatever you do, dont map esc to something else. Map something else to esc.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Usually, `C-[` is also a way to get out of insert mode. Some people like to map `jj` in insert mode as a way to exit and return to normal mode. I personally prefer `jh` as my fingers 'slide' better with this and I don't strain my middle finger much.

From somewhere in my neovim settings:

```
inoremap jh <Esc>
```

This remaps `jh` to escape in insert mode.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Ctrl-[ is the same as 'ESC'

Comment: I played around and also discovered this works: ":inoremap <F1> <Esc>". This maps the F1 key in the place of the Esc key.  This can be shortened to ":ino <F1> <Esc>".

Comment: Also, the capital letters aren't necessary.

Comment: Yeah, capitals aren't necessary and 'ino' is shorter to write, but in my configs I prefer brevity over cool-shortcuts. I'm glad I helped!

Comment: While brevity is cool and everything...it's the soul of wit after all...I'm guessing you meant something else. Clarity? Verbosity? Non-brevity? ;)

Comment: @BLayer, maybe. I am allowed to bend the exact meaning of words as I am not a native speaker or a cucumber-soup.

Comment: Mmmmmm. Cucumber soup.

Comment: How to undo that?

Comment: Undoing that `iunmap jh`

Answer (score 25):

## TL;DR

It's actually nice to remap <kbd>esc</kbd> to the home row. Here's how you decide what to map it to: pick a hand and roll your 4 fingers across your desktop as fast as you can in whichever direction is fastest. Use that to choose what keys to remap.

For me it's more natural to roll from pinky to index finger. Therefore I chose to use `kj`. Also, I did a `grep -rHin kj ~/src` (recursive grep on the parent directory of all my source code) and found no matches.

```
" esc in insert & visual mode
inoremap kj <esc>
vnoremap kj <esc>

" esc in command mode
cnoremap kj <C-C>
" Note: In command mode mappings to esc run the command for some odd
" historical vi compatibility reason. We use the alternate method of
" exiting which is Ctrl-C
```

Note: If you do need to type a literal `kj` (or whatever your mapping is) just type them with 2 seconds in between. (You'll see the cursor hesitate to move after the 1st char. Wait for it to move before typing the 2nd.)

You can shorten this delay by setting a shorter timeout to `timeoutlen`. For example, to have a timeout of 500ms add the following to your vimrc:

```
set timeoutlen=500
```

---

I have been using `vim` for 19 years. I was horrified when Apple updated their MacBook Pros to have a touch bar and no physical <kbd>esc</kbd> key. [I saw a post](https://csswizardry.com/2017/01/preparing-vim-for-apples-touch-bar/) that suggested mapping `jj` and `jk` to `<Esc>` and hated it. But I patiently jotted down on an index card every time it annoyed me. About 15 minutes later I reviewed my notes and came up with the **TL;DR** above to address the following:

1. I tend to hit <kbd>esc</kbd> a lot when I'm not in insert mode just to "be sure" and `jj` would drop me 2 lines.
2. `jk` is a no-op (down, up) but `kj` is more natural for my hands.
3. I also need to use <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit command mode without completing the command.

It's my hope that I can finally break my habit of hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> in other applications and closing windows when I'm several minutes into writing. I'd much rather insert stray **kj** characters than lose my work!

Comment: Note, for your cnoremap, when the esc comes from a mapping, it will execute the command, rather than aborting it. That is for compatibility reasons with vi

Comment: In both insert and command mode, esc still works. But, you also have this alternative home row combo that you also use. Maybe I didn't follow your point.

Comment: the point is, for command mode, an escape that comes from the mapping will not abort the command, but run it. Try `:ls kj`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt you are correct. What can be done about it? Or at least, where is this documented? I can't even come up with decent search terms to find anything about this.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the mapping to Ctrl-C which also exists command mode. I had to come up with that on my own. I cannot find the issue (or Ctrl-C) documented or discussed anywhere. I'd love to link to a reference if you can find one. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I don't remember whether this is being documented, I stumbled over that behaviour several years ago. Ah, it is kind of documented at `:h c_Esc`:  **In macros [...] start entered command.**  (Macros usually also include mappings)

Comment: Given the lack of physical escape key I've gotten into the habit of pressing `C-[` to generate an escape.   Unfortunately I also have a habit of mis-hitting even that and pressing`C-]` which then brings up the CTag completion list.   To resolve that I've just added `inoremap <C-]> <Esc>`

Comment: what about exiting the visual selector mode? not sure how its called, but when you press `v` how can you exit there?

Comment: @Toskan I added `vnoremap` for you. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky great tip on `<C-c>` being the desired escape mapping in command mode. Using `<Esc>` for it all this time has been giving me grief.

Answer (score 4):

**If you have a non-English keyboard layout, you can turn the extra keys into your advantage!**

For example, Hungarian layout has the <kbd>ö</kbd> (o umlaut) where <kbd>0</kbd> would be on an English keyboard. Most would never use this letter in vim.

So I just remap <kbd>Esc</kbd> to it everywhere without fear. But as [Bruno found out](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18081), in command mode remapping to <kbd>Esc</kbd> alters the behaviour, so there we use the equivalent <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>:

```
nnoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Normal mode
inoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Insert and Replace mode
vnoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Visual and Select mode
xnoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Visual mode
snoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Select mode
cnoremap ö <C-C>         " Remap in Command-line mode
onoremap ö <esc>         " Remap in Operator pending mode
```

If you miss the ability to type that letter, you can simply assign it to <kbd>Ctrl+ö</kbd> in insert and command mode. (I can't think of an use for it in other modes, but of course you can add the bindings to all of them.)

```
inoremap <C-ö> ö         " Remap in Insert and Replace mode
cnoremap <C-ö> ö         " Remap in Command-line mode
```

Put the above commands in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: They are not equivalent! Simple example: `5ii<esc>` vs `5ii<c-c>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I mean, (effectively) equivalent in *command* mode. But I'm not a Vim expert, so please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Oh, for some reason I jumped ahead without reading fully :) I think for `:` commands though C-c being Esc depends on a compatibility option, because Esc can be set to execute rather than cancel the command. And C-c always cancels, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `qwerty` keyboard and you cannot press `<C-[>`, simply `<C-C>` works fine ! And for any mode ! the only sad thing is the prompt when you press `<C-C>` in normal mode, telling you that you should press `:qa` to quit vim.

Comment: See my comment on Neinstein’s answer. *They are not equivalent, it will not work “just fine”.*

Comment: thanks for that, i did not know that they where not the same !