# How to remap escape in *vi* (not vim)?

Tags: escape, original-vi

I've used the information in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16963/remap-esc-key-in-vim) previously, but recently encountered a minimal installation with only vi. I edited the .vimrc in the user's home folder (`~/.vimrc`), but when typing `jj`, the literal text `<esc>` was entered within insert mode.

How does one do an inoremap for the escape key in vi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key syntax with brackets, such as `<Esc>`, is specific to Vim.

In plain vi, you need to enter an *actual* ESC character in your mapping.

You can do so by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>, which will insert an actual ESC and will be displayed as `^[`.

The command will look like:

```
:inoremap jj ^[
```

But note that the `^[` is a single ESC character and is entered with the sequence described above.

Comment: Thank you - I am familiar with escape sequences, but didn't realize this was required for vi. Will this also work in vim? I.e.: Can I use this for my .vimrc and whatever the analog file is for vi?

Comment: Yes, literal escape sequences will work for Vim as well. In fact, they'll work in Vim even in compatible mode. The vi init file is typically `~/.exrc`.